# Why Parallel Merge is faster in 11g

Tags: indexing, oracle11g, merge

I have a table of ~25M records and a procedure which updates a field in this table for almost 40K rows.

the field is included in some indexes. The question is:

using  << update  set ..where... >> is very slow with indexes such that I have to drop the indexes, perform the update reasonably quickly then recreate the indexes costing almost 5 minutes.

using parallel merge, I have been told that it would be faster but I'm wondering why it would be faster? even with indexes or I would have to drop the indexes again?

what is the philosophy behind the merge statement which makes it faster?

Many thanks,

Comment: Updating 40,000 rows out of 25 million shouldn't take 5 minutes.  I'd be concerned if it took 5 seconds on anything approaching reasonable hardware.  If you have a single `update` statement, I would guess that either the problem is a bad query plan.

Comment: Or triggers or bad hardware

Comment: Running 40,000 separate requests on the other hand could take some time. Bundling the updates into a single query would be a massive speedup if this hasn't already been done.

Comment: When indexes are there, it takes almost 5 mins but if I drop the indexes that include the updated field, it would take almost 20 seconds. BTW, the update statement is very straight forward and set-based. Hardware is also a good one.